# How to use copy to clipboard in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

I have to copy data of a certian field to the clipboard when the textbutton.icon is pressed.How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

Try below code, refer [**`setData`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/Clipboard/setData.html) and [**`ClipboardData`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/ClipboardData-class.html) or you can be use [**`clipboard`**](https://pub.dev/packages/clipboard) package

import below library/package in your code

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Your Widget:

```
    InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Clipboard.setData(
            ClipboardData(
              text: "Your Copy text",
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Text("Your Copy text"),
      ),
```

Comment: Should be the selected answer, learn more: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/106046#issuecomment-1171626179

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

Using ClipBoard

```
// copy to clipboard
Future<void> _copyToClipboard() async {
    await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: "Text to be copied"));
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
      content: Text('Copied to clipboard'),
    ));
  }

IconButton(
icon: const Icon(Icons.copy),
                onPressed: _copyToClipboard,
              ),


// Get Data From System Clipboard
String _textValue = '';

void _getClipboard() async {
    ClipboardData data = await Clipboard.getData(Clipboard.kTextPlain);
    setState(() {
      _textValue = data.text;
    });
  }

// or You can replace Clipboard.kTextPlain with text/plain to getData // from Clipboard.

ClipboardData data = await Clipboard.getData('text/plain');
```

Using Selectable Text

```
SelectableText(
"text to be copied" ?? "",
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 48),
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(copy: true, selectAll: true),
),
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried googling?

First google result:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

onTap: () {
  Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: "your text"));
},
```

source: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/dart/how+to+copy+text+to+clipboard+flutter